# Invoke-RestMethod REST API PUT Method with If-Match Error

Tags: rest, put

I am trying to use the PUT method in my REST API and in that i want to USE If-Match in header so in there i am getting Invalid that If-Match error everything is correct and all restapi and If-Match condition is runnable and execute in POSTMAN

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: $headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    "If-Match" = "4a1379d4-0000-0600-0000-645632570000"
}

getting error at if-match value row